# docker compose wait to create service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wait

I'm using docker compose to deploy my app, but I have a need to create a user in one service, and setting its API key on an env file before creating another service.

I'm using a docker-compose.yml with an init service to create user and set env variable with APItoken.

the `init` service waits for myapp to be healthy, and then, `entrypoint.sh` creates a user via REST api on myapp and sets is credentials on `vars.env`.
`apiclient` waits for `init` to complete, and gets the user credentials on `vars.env` set by `init`.

The problem is: when doing `docker compose up -d` the `apiclient` service is created immediately, and only waits `init` without starting. Therefore, because it is already created, the `vars.env` is not updated automatically to `apiclient`.

To make it work, I have to do `docker compose up -d` again, so that is detects the `vars.env` file modification and recreates `apiclient`.

Is is possible to config it so that `apiclient` waits to be **created** instead of waiting to **start**??? or, alternatively, automatically **recreated** services os execute docker-compose.yaml in two steps?

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  init: # Used to create user on myapp
    image: myapp
    entrypoint: ["/entrypoint.sh"]
    volumes:
      - ./config/entrypoint.sh:/entrypoint.sh
      - /data/env/vars.env:/vars.env
    env_file:
      - /data/env/vars.env
    depends_on:
      myapp:
        condition: service_healthy

  myapp:
    image: myapp
    restart: unless-stopped
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-z", "localhost", "8080"]
    env_file:
      - /data/env/vars.env

  apiclient:
    image: apiclient
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      init:
        condition: service_completed_sucessfully
    env_file:
      - /data/env/vars.env
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use health checks to check if "myapp" is running or not. Please refer to the doc for all the details: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck

Comment: I'm already using it. The problem is that  "apiclient" is created (not started) before "init" is completed. I'm assuming, that env file is mounted during creation not during start.

Comment: ohh my bad, have you tried having the apiclient depending on the myapp container instead of init ? with the condition being service_healthy ?

Comment: Tried here... it didn't work.